# Drag specific object

Tags: iphone, sdk

I have a problem with dragging object in iPhone sdk , my UIImageView outlet is red and I don't know why the dragging doesn't work ! but when remove the if line my code works fine , here is the code :

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];

    if ([touch view] == red) {
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    red.center = location;  

    }
}


- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

        [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
```

Comment: you must write the position of your object on "touchesMoved" with CGPoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you override touchesBegan of a UIView sub class, only the touches delivered to that UIView are handled there.

For its subviews you need to set UserInteractionEnabled to TRUE. And then make a subclass for your subviews through which you can delegate the touch handling back to your SuperView.

If that sounds complex, just use
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

Comment: thank you , momeks rights ! , I want drag this object around the screen

Comment: Yeah.. I was just answering you part where you wanted to do it only if the view was (red)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I did it with below code. I have to drag imageEnd in specific horizontal and vertical way so I bound them as below.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: touch.view];
location.x=510.0;
[imgEndPoint setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];

if ([touch view] == imgEndPoint) {
    if (location.y < 710.0 && location.y > 75.0) {//image move between this coordinate
        imgEndPoint.center = location;
    }
}
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

if ([touch view] == imgEndPoint) {

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: self.view];
    location.x=510.0;
    if (location.y < 710.0 && location.y > 75.0) {
    imgEndPoint.center = location;
        [self getPixcel];
    }
    [imgEndPoint setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
}
}
```